# How to create a string from active record model attributes names and values separated by a separator |?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model called **Student**, and **Student.first** has following attributes:

```
reg_no: "ABC001",school_fees: 10000.0,transaction_date: "2017-08-19"
```

I want to convert this into this:

```
reg_no=ABC001|school_fees=10000.0|transaction_date=2017-08-19
```

and assign it to a variable to perform encryption and decryption in that variable. How can I get this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
student = Student.first
student.attributes.map { |key, value| "#{key}=#{value}" }.join('|')
```